# Understanding LFS environment setup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, linux-from-scratch

I have some questions regarding the suggested setup from LFS.

***Question:***

- what is this command really doing

> cat > ~/.bash_profile << "EOF"
>       exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
>       EOF

- it mentions that the "new instance of the shell is a non-login shell" so we have to setup .bashrc   ....however it doesn't really explains how we use this bashrc once created. It goes back to bash_profile at the end.

*Most of it is well explained, but perhaps it is more technical for this section than what I expected and it also involves some important concepts I would like to understand in greater detail. I have marked in bold some commands I am unable to understand what they are doing.*

From: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/settingenvironment.html

Set up a good working environment by creating two new startup files for the bash shell. While logged in as user lfs, issue the following command to create a new .bash_profile:

```
cat > ~/.bash_profile << "EOF"
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
EOF
```

When logged on as user lfs, the initial shell is usually a login shell which reads the /etc/profile of the host and then .bash_profile. **The exec env -i.../bin/bash command in the .bash_profile file replaces the running shell with a new one with a completely empty environment, except for the HOME, TERM, and PS1 variables.** This ensures that no unwanted and potentially hazardous environment variables from the host system leak into the build environment.

**The new instance of the shell is a non-login shell, which does not read the /etc/profile or .bash_profile files, but rather reads the .bashrc file instead.** Create the .bashrc file now:

```
cat > ~/.bashrc << "EOF"
set +h
umask 022
LFS=/mnt/lfs
LC_ALL=POSIX
LFS_TGT=$(uname -m)-lfs-linux-gnu
PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
export LFS LC_ALL LFS_TGT PATH
EOF
```

The set +h command turns off bash's hash function. Hashing is ordinarily a useful feature—bash uses a hash table to remember the full path of executable files to avoid searching the PATH time and again to find the same executable. However, the new tools should be used as soon as they are installed. By switching off the hash function, the shell will always search the PATH when a program is to be run. As such, the shell will find the newly compiled tools in $LFS/tools as soon as they are available without remembering a previous version of the same program in a different location.

Setting the user file-creation mask (umask) to 022 ensures that newly created files and directories are only writable by their owner, but are readable and executable by anyone **(assuming default modes are used by the open(2) system call**, new files will end up with permission mode 644 and directories with mode 755).

The LFS variable should be set to the chosen mount point.

The LC_ALL variable controls the localization of certain programs, making their messages follow the conventions of a specified country. If the host system uses a version of Glibc older than 2.2.4, having LC_ALL set to something other than “POSIX” or “C” (during this chapter) **may cause issues if you exit the chroot environment and wish to return later**. Setting LC_ALL to “POSIX” or “C” (the two are equivalent) ensures that everything will work as expected in the chroot environment.

**The LFS_TGT variable sets a non-default, but compatible machine description for use when building our cross compiler and linker** and when cross compiling our temporary toolchain. More information is contained in Section 5.2, “Toolchain Technical Notes”.

Finally, to have the environment fully prepared for building the temporary tools, source the just-created user profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

```
cat > ~/.bash_profile << "EOF" exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash EOF
```

In that, `env` summons a new interactive non-login bash (`/bin/bash`) instance with environmental variables ignored (`-i`) besides those set explicitly. Non-login bash instances don't read `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` and `.profile`, but read `.bashrc`. Login instances however read those files but not `.bashrc`. Since `env` doesn't pass `-l` to `/bin/bash`, bash would not run as a login shell.

And `exec` overwrites the current shell process with env. `env` on the other hand `exec`'s bash so it's like over-all the old shell is transformed to a new bash but the process ID would still be the same.